# Sum a group of column with a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Statement that selects a group of data based on values.

```
Select case when Count(score) >= 2 then 2 else Count(score) end as Count
        from table 
        where questions = answered and score= 3
        group by Surveyid
```

This prints out the following (which is correct)

[image]

I ultimately need all of these values added together. I have come up with this but am getting an error and can't seem to resolve the issue.

```
Select Sum(*)
From (   Select case when Count(score) >= 2 then 2 else Count(score) end as Count
            from table 
            where questions = answered and score= 3
            group by Surveyid ) C
```

Comment: You can't use SUM(*), you should use SUM(<column_name>)

Comment: Case expression, not statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue.

```
Select Sum(Count)
From (   Select case when Count(score) >= 2 then 2 else Count(score) end as Count
            from table 
            where questions = answered and score= 3
            group by Surveyid ) C
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of Sum(*), try

```
Select Sum(C.Count)
```